# Why doesn't my for loop continue when I keep clicking?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, break

```
function nextCar() {
  var i;
  for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    var x = document.getElementById("boxright");
     x.innerHTML = cars[i].brand ;
  }
}
```

This is the function Im trying to fix. What I want it to do, is whenever I click a button (that has an onclick of nextCar(), I want it to go to the NEXT car in my array.What its doing now, is I will click my button and it will say "jaguar" in the element, but I want it to keep writing the next items in the arrays every time I click the button. Heres the code on top for perpective:

```
function car(brand, color, tire, window){
    this.brand = brand;
    this.color = color;
    this.tire = tire;
    this.window = window;
}
var Jaguar = new car("jaguar", "black", "m13", "tinted");
var Porsche = new car("Porsche", "red", "h3h3", "rollable");
var Fiat = new car("Fiat", "purple", "gauge", "clear");
var Bentley = new car("Bentley", "white", "twenties", "electric");
var cars = [Jaguar, Porsche, Fiat, Bentley];
```

Comment: Function is missing closing curly bracket?

Comment: To print the next car only you also need to declare i=0 before the function, remove the for loop and increase i by one before closing the function.

Comment: You don't need for loop at all

Answer (score 0):

You could use the array's [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) and get the next brand.

For displaying all other brands, you need to keep the former values.

```js
function Car(brand, color, tire, window) { // use upper case names for instanciable functions
    this.brand = brand;
    this.color = color;
    this.tire = tire;
    this.window = window;
}

function nextCar() {
    var x = document.getElementById("boxright"),
        item = iterator.next();

    if (!item.done) {
        x.innerHTML += item.value.brand + ' ';
    }
}

var jaguar = new Car("Jaguar", "black", "m13", "tinted"),
    porsche = new Car("Porsche", "red", "h3h3", "rollable"),
    fiat = new Car("Fiat", "purple", "gauge", "clear"),
    bentley = new Car("Bentley", "white", "twenties", "electric"),
    cars = [jaguar, porsche, fiat, bentley],
    iterator = cars[Symbol.iterator]();
```

```html
<button onclick="nextCar()">Click</button>
<p id="boxright"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, but what that did is make all 4 of the items in the array show up, instead of each one individually showing up every time I click my button.

Comment: I think he needs to iterate the cars array to the next item everytime when button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the `i` variable outside of the function.

Also, you can place an optional condition which will *re-iterate* your given cars array.

```
i = 0;
function nextCar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("boxright");
  x.innerHTML = cars[i].brand ;
  i++;
  if(i == cars.length)
    i = 0;
}
```

```js
function car(brand, color, tire, window){
  this.brand = brand;
  this.color = color;
  this.tire = tire;
  this.window = window;
}

var Jaguar = new car("jaguar", "black", "m13", "tinted");
var Porsche = new car("Porsche", "red", "h3h3", "rollable");
var Fiat = new car("Fiat", "purple", "gauge", "clear");
var Bentley = new car("Bentley", "white", "twenties", "electric");
var cars = [Jaguar, Porsche, Fiat, Bentley];
i = 0;
function nextCar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("boxright");
  x.innerHTML = cars[i].brand ;
  i++;
  if(i == cars.length)
    i = 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "nextCar()">Click</button>
<p id="boxright"></p>
```

Comment: @Sareda, you're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of writing the JavaScript code for the issue you are having is shown below:

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <h2>Testing:</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Next Car" onclick="nextCar()" >
    <div id="my-div">
        <p id="output"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

*test.js:*

```
function Car(brand, color, tire, window){
    this.brand = brand;
    this.color = color;
    this.tire = tire;
    this.window = window;
}

let Jaguar = new Car("Jaguar", "black", "m13", "tinted");
let Porsche = new Car("Porsche", "red", "h3h3", "rollable");
let Fiat = new Car("Fiat", "purple", "gauge", "clear");
let Bentley = new Car("Bentley", "white", "twenties", "electric");
let cars = [Jaguar, Porsche, Fiat, Bentley];

var i = 0;

function nextCar() {
    if (i == cars.length) {
        console.log("That was the last car!");
        return;
    }
    let output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML = cars[i++].brand;
}
```